# Cannot do raw printing from online website

Tags: php, printing, dot-matrix

I have a function to do raw printing like this:

```
function execPrint($pPrinterShareName, $pInit, $pData)
{       
    $tmpdir = sys_get_temp_dir();   # temporary directory to save temporary file
    $x = 0;
    $file =  tempnam($tmpdir, 'cetak_struk__'.$pInit.'_'.$x);  # temporary file name that will be printed
    $handle = fopen($file, 'w');                
    fwrite($handle, $pData);
    fclose($handle);        

    sleep(1);

    chmod($file, 0777);
    $v='';
    $v = copy($file, "//localhost/".$pPrinterShareName);
    sleep(1);
    return $v; 
}
```

this function will create a temporary folder and put a temporary file there. Then the file will be printed by copying that file to my localhost printer. $pPrinter

I can do this if my application is in my localhost, but how can I do that if my application is in an online hosting? Please help...

Comment: Just send a print version of the document to the browser. Or if you want to get it more automated without any confirmation, you have to write a local script which requests the resource from the webserver. There's no way to control client system's hardware from a webhost for security reasons.

Comment: Think what could happen when every website you visit could store arbitrary data, even executable, on your system in any place and use your local printer to print out spam.